# how to set android linux kernel command line parameter

Tags: android, embedded-linux

I would like to control cpu affinity on an Android device to isolate a core for use by a Linux-level application.

How to do this in Linux using the **isolcpus** kernel boot command line parameter is documented, but all descriptions I find use Grub to set the kernel command line.

How can I do this for the Linux on an Android device where this is no Grub?

Can I set kernel parameters for Android Linux without building a custom kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that it depends on the kernel in use and the bootloader.  Most Android devices are ARM based, so the option may or may not be available in your kernel.  GRUB is used for x86 desktop PCs, but typically with an ARM system uboot or a handful of other bootloaders may be used.

Answer (score 5):

There are tons of ways of doing it:-

Option 1: Edit system image: /device///BoardConfig.mk

Option 2: Edit kernel device tree: example msm8917.dtsi

```
chosen {
                bootargs = "androidboot.selinux=permissive";
        };
```

Option 3: Edit kernel config:-

```
+CONFIG_CMDLINE="foo=1"
+CONFIG_CMDLINE_EXTEND=y
```

Check runtime:-

```
#cat /proc/cmdline
```